# Set instance variable

Tags: ruby

If I have a specific value assigned to an instance variable, how do I define a method to reassign the value of this variable? When I run the code below in `rspec`, I keep getting the original value.

```
class Test
 def name 
   @name = 'me'
 end

 def name=(input)
   @name = input
 end
end
```

Comment: Which RSpec code do you run ? The Test class does nothing by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def name 
  @name = 'me'
end
```

Every time you call the method above, you set `@name` to `'me'` and return it.

I believe you are looking for the `||=` operator

```
def name
  @name ||= 'me' # only set @name to 'me' if it is not already set
end
```

IMO, the best way to accomplish a default value for `@name` is:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize
    @name = 'me'
  end
end
```

example:

```
t = Test.new
t.name
 # => "me" 
t.name = 'foo'
 # => "foo" 
t.name
 # => "foo"
```

Comment: perfect, forgot about that operator. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you're setting the `@name` variable in the getter, where you should only be returning it. Like so:

```
class Test
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(input)
    @name = input
  end
end
```

Or more simply you should just use the `attr_accessor` method to declare boilerplate versions of the getter and setter methods. Like so:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial value should be set in the constructor method.

```
class Test
 def initialize
   @name = 'me'
 end

 def name 
   @name
 end

 def name=(input)
   @name = input
 end
end
```

And you could use `attr_accessor` to make you code simple:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize
    @name = 'me'
  end
end
```